# (line-pixel-height)

Tags: formatting

I've a block of 10 or so lines.
Some show 19  pixels using 
`M-x eval-expression` `(line-pixel-height)`  - this looks normal for
my settings.
Others, however, appear about 3 lines high and show 66 pixels high?

Each time I hit newline (in this 'bad' region) I get the 66px line height.

Quite stumped!  Any suggestions please

Comment: You could try first in a buffer with no major-mode other than `fundamental-mode`.  If the problem goes away in a `fundamental-mode` buffer, then you can inspect the properties on the text in the affected region by placing your cursor in the area affected and type `C-u C-x =` to see what is there at point.  If you have adjusted size and/or height of certain faces and/or played around with line spacing settings, then those are likely suspects.  If you still have problems in a `fundamental-mode` buffer (*with no minor-modes active*), then try with zero user-configuration (aka `emacs -Q`).

Comment: Nothing in text-mode, nor in the rest of the affected buffer? The character at point is newline, hence my queries with line-pixel-height?

I'm not sure how / why its value would change?